# Haskell: Calculate the length of a list using (curry snd)

Tags: list, haskell, fold, currying

I was given an assignment to calculate the length of a list using the `foldr` Haskell function, so I did these two examples

```
flength :: [a] -> Int
flength = foldr (\ _ n -> n+1) 0

flength' :: [a] -> Int
flength' l = foldr aux 0 l
    where
        aux _ n = n+1
```

Then, as a personal challenge, the professor asked us to use the `snd` function and yesterday I came up with this:

```
flength'' :: [a] -> Int
flength'' = foldr ((+1).(curry snd)) 0
```

What I want to happen is that this function will turn the head of the list `h` and the accumulator `0` into the pair `(h,0)` then return `0` and after that apply it to the function `(+1)`

I expected this to be done recursively, effectively giving me the length of the list at the end.

Instead, I get this error message:

```
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( f1.hs, interpreted )

f1.hs:54:24: error:
    * No instance for (Num (Int -> Int))
        arising from an operator section
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In the first argument of `(.)', namely `(+ 1)'
      In the first argument of `foldr', namely `((+ 1) . (curry snd))'
      In the expression: foldr ((+ 1) . (curry snd)) 0 xs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why is this happening and how can I get this code to work?

Comment: try `((+1) .) . curry snd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us lay all our tools in front of us, like a good artisan does:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
snd   :: (a, b) -> b
```

First, we note that `snd` and `foldr` do not really fit well. So let's use `curry`, just like you did, and add `curry snd` to our small tool library:

```
foldr     :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
curry snd ::  a -> b -> b
```

This looks *very* promising. Now we need to add `1` to the result of `curry snd`, otherwise we're just writing `flip const`. Let's start with a lambda:

```
\a b -> 1 + curry snd a b
= \a b -> ((+1) . curry snd a) b
```

We can now shove of `b` and end up with

```
\a -> (+1) . curry snd a
= \a -> (.) (+1) (curry snd a)
= \a -> ((.) (+1)) (curry snd a)
= \a -> (((.) (+1)) . curry snd) a
```

Now we can eta-reduce `a` from both sides too and end up with

```
(((.) (+1)) . curry snd) = ((+1) . ) . curry snd
```

Therefore, your third variant would be

```
flength'' = foldr (((+1) . ) . curry snd) 0
```

Now, why did you get your error message? You were close with `(+1) . curry snd`, but the types don't work out:

```
(+1)      :: Int -> Int
--            v                    v
(.)       :: (b ->  c)    -> (a -> b       ) -> a -> c
curry snd ::                  t -> (x -> x)
              ^                     ^
```

But in your case, the `b`s in `(.)`'s signature didn't match. One of them was an `Int`, the other was a function.

**TL;DR**: If you want to write `f (g x y)` point-free, write `((f.) . g)`